# Why doesn't background-image change?

Tags: jquery, css

JavaScript section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            setTimeout('slideback()', 1000);
            function slideback()
            {
                $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
            }
        });
</script>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
                background-image:url('taksi.jpg');
                background-size:100%; 
                background-attachment:fixed;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                src='taksi.jpg',
                sizingMethod='scale')";
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                src='taksi.jpg',
                sizingMethod='scale');
            }
```

After 1000 miliseconds, it should change but doesn't.  Why not?  How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JS console? Is the image you are loading really there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`slideback` is scoped inside the DOM ready handler scope. By passing a string to `setTimeout`, you're invoking a global eval of it. Instead, pass the function as reference:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
      setTimeout(slideback, 1000);
      function slideback() {
          $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `'slideback()'` as a string literal to `setTimeout()` it will run that code *after* the `$(document).ready()` function, at which point your function definition is no longer accessible from outside.

You can avoid many scope issues by using an anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
}, 1000);
```

Or, by passing the function *reference* instead of the name:

```
setTimeout(slideback, 1000);
```

You could also move the definition outside of the `.ready()` function:

```
function slideback()
{
  $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
}

$(function() {
    setTimeout(slideback, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous function works better due to the scoping issues you had when passing a string to the timeout:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qbnjF/)

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
        },1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem just problem is in writing code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    function slideback()
    {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(http://sehirmedya.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/uluda%C4%9F.jpg)');
    }
    $('document').ready(function(){
        setTimeout(slideback, 1000);
    });
</script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: i didnt know it because i was typing at same time...sorry for being late....but its doesn't matter its more IMP that he got good help you guys on time...Thanx

Comment: And don't pass a string to setTimout